# converting \s+ delimited file to csv using sed

Tags: csv, sed

I'm trying to convert a file that has two or more white spaces separating each column.

```
YP_010083342.1       -            258 VOG00003             -            582   8.6e-22   80.7   0.2   1   1   5.3e-25     1e-21   80.4   0.2   193   363     5   185     1   251 0.60 anti-repressor protein [Staphylococcus phage LH1]
```

I'd like to convert this to a csv using sed. The following sed commands make no apparent changes to the file.

```
sed -i 's/\s+/,/g' file.ouput
sed -i 's/$\s+/,/g' file.ouput
sed -i 's/\t+/,/g' file.ouput
sed -i 's/$\t+/,/g' file.ouput
```

but the following command results in the following

```
sed -i 's/\s\s/,/g' file.ouput

YP_010083342.1,,, -,,,,,,258 VOG00003,,,,,, -,,,,,,582, 8.6e-22, 80.7, 0.2, 1, 1, 5.3e-25,, 1e-21, 80.4, 0.2, 193, 363,, 5, 185,, 1, 251 0.60 anti-repressor protein [Staphylococcus phage LH1]
```

Is anyone able to explain why this is occurring and how to properly solve this?

Comment: Maybe trying with `\h` instead of `\s`...?

Comment: Why is "using sed" part of the question? Would you really not accept an answer that used awk, or was implemented in pure native bash with no external tools?

Comment: I'd be happy with an answer in awk or other tools, but I'd particularly like to improve my understanding of how this sed command works.

Comment: In that case, the best place might be to start with the [relevant POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116). Note that POSIX-standardized `sed` doesn't support `\s`, so that's better avoided. Use `[[:space:]]` instead for better compatibility, when you want to match different kinds of spaces.

Comment: (Among the links you'll find in the above specification is one to [BRE regex syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), which specifies the regular expression format that all standard-compliant `sed` versions are required to support; some go beyond that standard, but when you write to the standard you know your code will run everywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/ {2,}/,/g' file

YP_010083342.1,-,258 VOG00003,-,582,8.6e-22,80.7,0.2,1,1,5.3e-25,1e-21,80.4,0.2,193,363,5,185,1,251 0.60 anti-repressor protein [Staphylococcus phage LH1]
```

Or this `awk`:

```
awk -F ' {2,}' -v OFS=, '{$1=$1} 1' ff
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `+` is part of extended regular expressions, which have to be enabled using `sed -r` (or `-E`). Some seds such as GNU sed support it as an extension also in basic regular expressions, but it has to be escaped: `\+`. `\s` is also an extension, by the way.

Assuming GNU sed, any of these would work:

```sh
sed -i 's/\s\s\+/,/g' file.output
sed -E -i 's/\s\s+/,/g' file.output
sed -E -i 's/\s{2,}/,/g' file.output
```

More portable, working with any sed (redirect output to another file, then rename):

```sh
sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{2,\}/,/g' file.output
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful to understand, but unfortunately each of these lines replaces even single spaces with commas. This seems strange to me when specifying "\s+"?

Comment: @Tom no, that's expected, `+` is "one or more", I actually didn't see the "two or more" requirement...

Comment: @Tom I've updated to "two or more" blanks. That also means the `tr` solution wouldn't work.